# What was Randy Coven's gear

Tags: bass-guitar

I've been googling for it. He uses a Pavel "Randy Coven" signature series fretless bass and GK heads with ampeg cabs.

Does anyone knows which effects and strings did he use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually before the Pavel, Randy used (on his epic debut album) a couple Barrington Basses. At the time I believe he used Rotosound Light guaged strings at the time and a modified Pierce Preamp like Billy Sheehan's...